# PyPyODBC not inserting record to MS-SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I'm new to Python and wrote this simple code for inserting data to the SQL server:

```
import pypyodbc
connect = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Sql Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.;Database=SAMPLE;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = connect.cursor()
print('Trying to insert!')
cursor.execute("insert into [SAMPLE].[dbo].[Register] VALUES ('behzad','razzaqi')")
print('Insert Finish!')
connect.close()
```

The code executes fine and even me `Insert Finish!`, but when I check SQL server, there are no records inserted. What happened? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to do `cursor.commit()` for the changes to reflect!

Comment: Probably like all SQL databases : commit before closing the connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you must also call `connect.commit()`. Try:

```
import pypyodbc
connect = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Sql Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.;Database=SAMPLE;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = connect.cursor()
print('Trying to insert!')
cursor.execute("insert into [SAMPLE].[dbo].[Register] VALUES ('behzad','razzaqi')")
connect.commit()
print('Insert Finish!')
connect.close()
```

Comment: @chertchertopert, Thankn you, glad to help

Comment: enjoy your new voting privileges :)

Comment: @apomene have a complimentary upvote from a database noob (next time I'll flag that as a duplicate now that I know)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Thanks, I appreciate